# How to sum values in a DF column that are two individual values

Tags: r

i am unable to add column values in R in my DF. after reading the CSV, I need to calculate the individual cell values which have two values. How do I go about doing that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIJ7e.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We cannot read data into R from images. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(yourdata)`, if that is not too large.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Do not post picture of data because we can't copy/paste that into R.

Comment: you need to look up sub setting a data.frame.  But bear in mind you don't have any proper numbers in the columns except for the first one.  And, as everyone says, please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions with toy data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Variable = c("1-3", "40-45")
)
```

with `sapply`:

```
library(stringr)
sapply(lapply(str_extract_all(df$Variable, "\\d+"), as.numeric), sum)
[1]  4 85
```

with `map_dbl`:

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(
    # extract whatever digits are there:
    add = str_extract_all(df$Variable, "\\d+"),
    # map the digits to one another and add the first to the second:
    add = map_dbl(add, function(x) as.numeric(x)[1] + as.numeric(x)[2]))
  Variable add
1      1-3   4
2    40-45  85
```